# I think there's a slight mistake that my C++ textbook is giving me about switch statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int grade;
    int aCount;
    int bCount;
    int cCount;
    int dCount;
    int fCount;

    cout << "Enter the letter grades." << endl
        << "Enter the EOF character to end input." << endl;

    while ((grade = cin.get()) != EOF)
    {

        switch (grade)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            aCount++;
            break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            bCount++;
            break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            cCount++;
            break;

        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            dCount++;
            break;

        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            fCount++;
            break;

        case '\n':
        case '\t':
        case ' ':
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Incorrect letter grade entered." << "Enter a new grade." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nNumber of students who received each letter grade:"
        << "\nA: " << aCount
        << "\nB: " << bCount
        << "\nC: " << cCount << "\nD: " << dCount << "\nF: " << fCount << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is an exact code provided by my C++ textbook. While I was practicing these switch statement codes by copying these codes then compile it, my Visual Studio 2010 express keep gives me an error saying that "aCount is being used without assigned..." same applies to fCount. This program should read any letter from A to F from a keyboard then increment whatever letter that was recognized. I think there should be cin>>grade somewhere in the codes but I don't find it. By the way, can "cin.get()" could work as cin>>grade??

Comment: just initialize the integers to some value; you probably want 0; in C++11 `int aCount{};`, otherwise you can just `int aCount = 0;`

Comment: Yep, the problem isn't the switch statement. It's the lack of initialization of variables that the switch statement is using. That's what "...used without being assigned" means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are declaring your variables try giving them the value of 0 like this:

```
int grade = 0;
int aCount = 0;
int bCount = 0;
int cCount = 0;
int dCount = 0;
int fCount = 0;
```

This will ensure that you are in fact assigning a value to the variable before it is being used.

Then try to run it, I bet it works!

Comment: and what about `cin`?

Comment: `cin` is guaranteed to initialize `grade` (assuming that there is at least one grade), but there's no harm in initializing it to 0 before that happens.

Comment: @Max: No, a thing can only be initialised once. You're talking about assignment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'll accept the correction.  I was actually trying to not be too **informal**, and somehow ended up being sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable for you to initialize your variables being using it. Some compiler will not even give you a warning before compilation, but assigns some "garbage values" to your un-initialize variables.

Initializing your variables to 0 is suffice in this scenario (Like what other user mentioned).

```
    int grade=0;
    int aCount=0;
    int bCount=0;
    int cCount=0;
    int dCount=0;
    int fCount=0;
```

> By the way, can "cin.get()" could work as cin>>grade??

That depends on how you want to use it. `cin.get` can be used to extract a:

- single character
- multiple characters and store them as c-string (char array) or
- store them into a stream buffer object

from the input stream.

You may realize `cin.get` can't accept numbers, so if you are accepting input of characters or string, it is fine. But in future, if you want it to accept numbers, just use `cin >> number`

**An example on using cin.get()**

```
char cStr[50];
cin.get(cStr,5); //It will take n-1 characters
cout << cStr;

//Input: abcde
//Output: abcd
```

Comment: I'm not aware of _any_ compiler that refuses to warn about uninitialised variables. You do generally have to ensure that you turn warnings on, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Most compilers will provide warning now a days, but some older compilers like "Quincy" which is still widely used in some universities do not provide warnings for uninitialized variables even when you set the warnings from "default" to "all".

Comment: Never heard of it. And it seems to be almost ten years old, if a useful tool for beginners.